# Unable to handle event in another class

Tags: vb.net

I am kinda new to visual basic and was wondering if it is possible to trigger events in a class, based on action with in form.

So the following is my problem:
I have a form called Main, with a picture box called picPID
And a class called add_new

What I want to do is:
when the right mousebutton is clicked, the code for the event handling is placed within the class called add_new

I thought i could just declare it in the following way:

Sub meMouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Main.picPID.MouseDown

But I get an error saying i have to declare it withEvents, I tried to declare the picturebox as:

Public shared withEvents as picturebox

but it dident help, any sugestions? It is not a problem having the code within the Main form, but it would result in a lot of code, so I was hoping to split it up.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea. Splitting the UI functionality of the form in separate classes makes them depend on each other. It seems to violate some basic principle of OOP. Perhaps, if you want to create reusable code for a PictureBox functionality, you should try to EXTEND the PictureBox class creating your PictureBox derived class

Comment: `Handles Main.picPID.MouseDown` is a pretty nasty VB.NET trap that you'll have to learn to avoid.  `Main` is a *type name* but an object reference is required.  VB.NET is too forgiving in allowing you to use `Main` in your code when you really mean an object.  It won't work here.  Anyhoo, you have to use the AddHandler statement here.

Answer (score 2):

So you have the class with an eventhandler:

```
Public Class add_new

    Public Sub PictureBoxEventHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        'Your Implementation
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then you need an instance of this class within the form containing the picturebox:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private add_New_Command As New add_new ' hold a reference to the command

    'constructor
    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        ' and add the handler to the event of the picture box ... hook it up
        AddHandler PictureBox1.MouseDown, AddressOf add_New_Command.PictureBoxEventHandler

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: this is how it would be done. but i'd rather follow the suggestion of @Steve and brush up on OOP design priciples before engaging the big stuff. there are tons of books to this topic out there and i recommend you get one of these... good stuff

Comment: Good solution, but make sure to remove the handler as well. Otherwise your memory can be unhandled and can get nasty...

Comment: @436f6465786572 should get garbage collected when theres no reference to the instance of Form1...